# How do I remove the directions of a vector from another vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have a vector $x$ and $n$  vectors $y_1 ... y_n$. They come from some vector space with inner product $<.,.>$.

I want to find $\arg\min_{x'} <x - x',  x-x'>$ such that $x'$ is orthogonal to all of $y_1 ... y_n$ (meaning $<x', y_i> = 0$, assuming $n$ is small enough).

I know how to do it for $n=1$ (just project), but not sure how to do it for $n > 1$.

Gram-Schmidt maybe somehow?

Comment: Project $x$ onto the orthogonal complement of the space spanned by the $y_i$.

Comment: Do you actually know how to do it when $n = 1$? Because the answer is a value of $x'$ is which orthonal to the vector $y_1$ you know. So "just project" isn't going to work, as you don't know what to project onto yet. Instead you need to remove the part of $x$ that is *not* orthogonal to $y$. When $n > 1$, the method is much the same.